# How to show that for the left shift operator, the continuous spectrum are precisely values where $|\lambda|=1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that for the left shift operator with $l^p$ norm for any $1\leq p <\infty$, the continuous spectrum are precisely the values where $|\lambda|=1$. I have shown the operator norm of the left-shift operator is 1 and the eigenvalues are all $\lambda <1$ Since the spectrum is bounded by 1 and closed, the remaining values of the spectrum must be where $|\lambda|=1$ Now my idea to show that for any $|\lambda|=1$ must be in the continuous spectrum, we need to show the range of $T-\lambda I$ is dense and one way to show, this is to show we can get any finite sequence we want since we can approximate infinite sequence with finite sequence. So for $a\in l^p$, we can consider the truncated sequence $a^N$ and try to solve $(T-\lambda I)x=a^N$ Now at this point, I am stuck because I am not sure how to construct the solution $x$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $q$ be the index conjugate to $p$. Suppose range of $T-\lambda I$ is not dense. Then there exist $y \in \ell^{q}\neq 0$ with $\sum ((Tx)_n-\lambda x_n)y_n=0$ for all $x \in \ell^{p}$. This implies $\sum (x_{n+1}-\lambda ) y_n=0$. Write $\sum x_{n+1}y_n$ in terms of  $\sum x_n y_{n-1}$ and you can now show easily that $y_n=0$ for all $n$.